# How to consolidate blocks of time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a derived table with a list of relative seconds to a foreign key (ID):

```
CREATE TABLE Times (
    ID INT
  , TimeFrom INT
  , TimeTo INT
);
```

The table contains mostly non-overlapping data, but there are occasions where I have a TimeTo < TimeFrom of another record:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | TimeFrom | TimeTo |
+----+----------+--------+
| 10 | 10       | 30     |
| 10 | 50       | 70     |
| 10 | 60       | 150    |
| 10 | 75       | 150    |
| .. | ...      | ...    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

The result set is meant to be a flattened linear idle report, but with too many of these overlaps, I end up with negative time in use. I.e. If the window above for `ID = 10` was 150 seconds long, and I summed the differences of relative seconds to subtract from the window size, I'd wind up with `150-(20+20+90+75)=-55`. This approach I've tried, and is what led me to realizing there were overlaps that needed to be flattened.

So, what I'm looking for is a solution to flatten the overlaps into one set of times:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | TimeFrom | TimeTo |
+----+----------+--------+
| 10 | 10       | 30     |
| 10 | 50       | 150    |
| .. | ...      | ...    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Considerations: Performance is very important here, as this is part of a larger query that will perform well on it's own, and I'd rather not impact its performance much if I can help it.

On a comment regarding "Which seconds have an interval", this is something I have tried for the end result, and am looking for something with better performance. Adapted to my example:

```
SELECT SUM(C.N)
FROM (
    SELECT A.N, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY A.N) RowID
    FROM 
          (SELECT TOP 60 1 N FROM master..spt_values) A
        , (SELECT TOP 720 1 N FROM master..spt_values) B
    ) C
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Times SE
        WHERE SE.ID = 10
            AND SE.TimeFrom <= C.RowID
            AND SE.TimeTo >= C.RowID
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM Times2 D
                WHERE ID = SE.ID
                    AND D.TimeFrom <= C.RowID
                    AND D.TimeTo >= C.RowID
            )
        GROUP BY SE.ID
    )
```

The problem I have with this solution is I have get a Row Count Spool out of the EXISTS query in the query plan with a number of executions equal to COUNT(C.*). I left the real numbers in that query to illustrate that getting around this approach is for the best. Because even with a Row Count Spool reducing the cost of the query by quite a bit, it's execution count increases the cost of the query as a whole by quite a bit as well.

Further Edit: The end goal is to put this in a procedure, so Table Variables and Temp Tables are also a possible tool to use.

Comment: Interesting question. My initial reaction is a scary one: a cursor might be in order. But I hope we can find you a solution that works a bit better than that.

Comment: so if you want sum(30-10,70-50, 150-60) i dont understand the "150-75" ? what do you mean with "mostly not overlapping"?  and why overlapping?

Comment: got it! you need a time line ...

Comment: I was going to sleep, but this will keep me up for a few minutes

Comment: are there some 'sure' borders of the values you have? are you only expecting int as answer? more input please! (eg, what db system/sql dialect) do you have a chance of denomalization?

Comment: Possible repeat...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206537/t-sql-script-logic-issues-with-timeline   I think you can use the solution to my question there

Comment: @halfbit, yes to the timeline, but how in TSQL? Also, dialect, DBMS are present as tags. There are no "sure" borders, save some ones coming in from an external reference (this will be put together in an OUTER APPLY).

Comment: @twelfth, I've got a "which seconds have an interval" solution, but I'm looking for a more performance-oriented approach. I'll post that solution as something I've tried.

Comment: @JaazCole: do you have the chance of doing some denomalisation?

Comment: @halfbit, only in table variables or temp tables.

Comment: @JaazCole - Yes, I hit the problem with that solution as well...I ended up scheduling it as a nightly job that took the results and plugged it into a table in a datawarehouse, then I'd refer to that table in the datawarehouse instead.Probably not feasible if you are looking for real time data...but unfortuntaely the only solution I can find. Hoepfully one of the guru's here has something better. SHame you are not in Oracle, I'm curious if the second solution there preforms better

Comment: @halfbit, The solution I posted returns in 2.3 seconds for the size of records I'm dealing with, and while I'm not expecting high traffic for this view, I'm hoping to reduce the run time.

Comment: @JaazCole: again I ask for more inforamtion. I have some funy ideas, but ...

Comment: @JaazCole What is the size of your set?

Comment: @halfbit, I'm sorry I must have been misunderstanding what you were asking for.

Comment: @EarlGElliottIII, properly constrained, about 600 records per execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join each row to its successor overlapping row on the same ID value (where such exist).

Now for each row in the result-set of `LHS left join RHS` the contribution to the elapsed time for the ID is:

`isnull(RHS.TimeFrom,LHS.TimeTo) - LHS.TimeFrom as TimeElapsed`

Summing these by ID should give you the correct answer.

Note that:
  - where there isn't an overlapping successor row the calculation is simply
 `LHS.TimeTo - LHS.TimeFrom`
 - where there is an overlapping successor row the calculation will net to
 `(RHS.TimeFrom - LHS.TimeFrom) + (RHS.TimeTo - RHS.TimeFrom)`
which simplifies to
  `RHS.TimeTo - LHS.TimeFrom`

Comment: This sounds like it might work if the expected degree of overlap was no greater than 1, and while I can extend this model to the amount of overlap I'm currently seeing in my sample, I feel that this may be a bit heavy in terms of processing power when it comes to the joins.

Comment: @JaazCole: Check it out - it will work for any degree of overlap. Only the final record in a set contributes it's entire elapsed time; every other record will contribute only its extension to the elapsed time. I have used this technique often in the past. Also, if there is an index on (ID,TimeFrom, other fields) then the join should be performant. Once again, wroite the query and look at the Query Plan.

Comment: @JaazCole: Important - only the one self-join is needed. There is no need for additional joins for additional degrees of overlap.

Comment: Better living through math! This appears to work great, but I feel like I may need a bit more guidance on details - I'm double-checking the inner result set (before summing) and found a few negative contributions..is this normal, or should I perhaps paste up the sample SQL I'm using? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never mind on that last request, it appears my last comment was in regards to GIGO data. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

OK. I'm still trying to do this with just one `SELECT`. But This totally works:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ID INT, GroupId INT, TimeFrom INT, TimeTo INT)

INSERT INTO @tmp
    SELECT ID, 0, TimeFrom, TimeTo 
    FROM Times
    ORDER BY Id, TimeFrom

DECLARE @timeTo int, @id int, @groupId int

SET @groupId = 0

UPDATE @tmp
SET 
    @groupId = CASE WHEN id != @id THEN 0 
                    WHEN TimeFrom > @timeTo THEN @groupId + 1 
                    ELSE @groupId END,
    GroupId = @groupId,
    @timeTo = TimeTo,
    @id = id    

SELECT Id, MIN(TimeFrom), Max(TimeTo) FROM @tmp 
GROUP BY ID, GroupId ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like below (assumes SQL 2008+ due to CTE):

```
    WITH Overlaps
    AS
    (
        SELECT  t1.Id, 
                TimeFrom = MIN(t1.TimeFrom), 
                TimeTo = MAX(t2.TimeTo)
        FROM    dbo.Times t1
            INNER JOIN dbo.Times t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
                                    AND t2.TimeFrom > t1.TimeFrom
                                    AND t2.TimeFrom < t1.TimeTo
        GROUP BY t1.Id
    )
    SELECT      o.Id,
                o.TimeFrom,
                o.TimeTo
    FROM    Overlaps o

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      t.Id,
                t.TimeFrom,
                t.TimeTo
    FROM    dbo.Times t
        INNER JOIN Overlaps o   ON o.Id = t.Id
                                AND (o.TimeFrom > t.TimeFrom OR o.TimeTo < t.TimeTo);
```

I do not have a lot of data to test with but seems decent on the smaller data sets I have.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrapped by head around this issue - and afterall I found, that the problem is your data.

You claim (if i get that right), that these entries should reflect the relative times, when a user goes idle / comes back.

So, you should consider to sanitize your data and refactor your inserts to produce *valid* data sets.
For instance, the two lines:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | TimeFrom | TimeTo |
+----+----------+--------+
| 10 | 50       | 70     |
| 10 | 60       | 150    |
```

*how* can it be possible that a user is idle *until* second 70, but goes idle on second 60? This already implies, that he has been back latest at around second 59.

I can only *assume* that this issue comes from different threads and/or browser windows (tabs) a user might be using your application with. (Each having it's own "idle detection")

So instead of *working-around* the symptoms - you should fix the cause! **Why** is this data entry inserted into the table? You could avoid this by simple checking, if the user is already idle before inserting a new row.

- Create a unique key constraint on `ID` and `TimeTo`
- Whenever an *idle-event* is detected, execute the following query:

  `INSERT IGNORE INTO Times (ID,TimeFrom,TimeTo)VALUES('10', currentTimeStamp, -1);
  -- (If the user is already "idle" - nothing will happen)`
- Whenever an *comeback-event* is detected, execute the following query:

  `UPDATE Times SET TimeTo=currentTimeStamp WHERE ID='10' and TimeTo=-1
  -- (If the user is already "back" - nothing will happen)`

The fiddle linked here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb17/1 would reproduce the chain of events for your example, but resulting in a clean and logical set of idle-windows:

```
ID   TIMEFROM   TIMETO

10   10         30 
10   50         70 
10   75         150
```

**Note:** The Output is slightly different from the output you desired. But I feel that this is more accurate, cause of the reason outlined above: A user *cannot* go idle on second 70 without returning from it's current idle state before. He either STAYS idle (and a second thread/tab runs into the idle-event) Or he returned in between.

---

**Especially for your need to maximize performance, you should fix the data and not invent a work-around-query. This is maybe 3 ms  upon inserts, but could be worth 20 seconds upon select!**

---

Edit: *if* Multi-Threading / Multiple-Sessions *is* the cause for the wrong insert, you would also need to implement a check, if `most_recent_come_back_time < now() - idleTimeout` - otherwhise a user might comeback on tab1, and is recorded idle on tab2 after a few seconds, cause tab2 did run into it's idle timeout, cause the user only refreshed tab1.

Comment: If I had control over application design, we would be having a very different discussion. I appreciate the input, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 'same' problem once with 'days' (additionaly without counting WE and Holidays)
The word **counting** gave me the following idea:

```
create table Seconds ( sec INT);
insert into Seconds values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9), ...

select count(distinct sec) from times t, seconds s
where s.sec between t.timefrom and t.timeto-1
and id=10;
```

you can cut the start to 0 (I put the '10' here in braces)

```
select count(distinct sec) from times t, seconds s
where s.sec between t.timefrom- (10) and t.timeto- (10)-1
and id=10;
```

and finaly

```
select count(distinct sec) from times t, seconds s,
(select min(timefrom) m from times where id=10) as m
where s.sec between t.timefrom-m.m and t.timeto-m.m-1
and id=10;
```

additionaly you can "ignore" eg. 10 seconds by dividing you loose some prezition but earn speed

```
select count(distinct sec)*d from times t, seconds s,
(select min(timefrom) m from times where id=10) as m,
(select 10 d) as d
where s.sec between (t.timefrom-m)/d and (t.timeto-m)/d-1
and id=10;
```

Sure it depends on the range you have to look at, but a 'day' or two of seconds should work (although i did not test it)

[fiddle ...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e5c23/30)